# How can i disable asynchronous functions and structures to be auto-generated?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, asynchronous, code-generation

I want to add web reference in my C# project in Visual Studio 2013. But when i do that, it creates a class with so many asynchronous functions and structures.

I do not use them. I prefer to use my own thread managing to call these methods but they made my executable file VERY LARGE.

How can i disable asynchronous functions and structures to be auto-generated?

**Edit:**

I figured out that the reason that there is no "Advanced" button is that my .net framework version is 2.0 and I am using web reference instead of service reference.
But i don't want to change my .net version.

Comment: Please define "VERY LARGE". I'm having a hard time believing simply including some extra asynchronous functionality in the auto-generated code could have a significant effect on the overall size of a .exe file that has non-trivial functionality in it. And is there something about simply deleting (or using `#if` around) the code you don't want included in your .exe that doesn't work in your scenario?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have to check and delete around 10,000 lines of code in order to delete or use #if. That is why I am looking for something automatic.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I started deleting the codes, when i was at the line 2,000 i changed the URL behavior from dynamic to static. then i saw that the codes are back!!!

Comment: @PeterDuniho After I deleted the async codes. the size of my dll reduced from 392 KBs to 253 KBs.

Comment: Just as I expected. Your .exe isn't "very large" in the first place, and by your own admission the extra code added only about 140KB. Granted, that's a big percentage change, but 400KB is in no sense of the phrase "very large" (never mind "VERY LARGE"). I'm sorry I don't know the answer to your question, but IMHO you should just not worry about it. The 140KB increase is only about 1/30,000th the physical RAM on today's low-end 4GB PC, and roughly a _millionth_ the total size of one of the smallest disks you can purchase today. I think your computer can handle that kind of load. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I appreciate your honesty and your great analysis. I confess that i have obsession.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screen shot]

If you right click references and select add service reference you will see the above

Comment: thanks but there is no "Advanced..." button in my Visual Studio 2013. I have the express edition.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at visual studio community edition. Its free but has all the features of professional edition.

Comment: I also have Visual Studio 2010 Premium edition but it does not have this button too. My friend has a VS 2010 ultimate. Do you think it might have the button?

Comment: I downloaded and installed it. Still there is no "Advanced" button.

Comment: I figured out that the reason there is no "Advanced" button is my .net framework version is 2.0 and I am using web reference instead of service reference.